# How to make setTimeout activate on last time a Toggle is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a .slideToggle to show a div once an image is clicked. I want the div to disappear 10 seconds after the last time the toggle is clicked. The problem is that if I click the image a few times, the duration is 10 seconds after the first click and not the last. If you view the fiddle (I used a shorter duration for testing) and click the image a few times you will see what I mean.

Does anyone have any idea how I can get this working as desired? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7fy536nv/

Requirements...

- The div should show for 10 seconds then disappear
- The div will disappear if the image is clicked again
- The div will disappear if something outside the div is clicked

**HTML**

```
<div class="box-new">
    <a href="box-link" id="box-link">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x60/ff0000/fff.png">
    </a>
</div>

<div id="empty-box">jkhsahg akjfhsajk fhas jklsad flkasd hfjkashd fjka sdkjfh adskjfhs dakjfh kafh sdah dhjaf</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
}

#empty-box {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: #000;
    top: 60px;
    width: 240px;
    padding: 20px;
    left: 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "open sans", "arial";
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 18px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#box-link').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $("#empty-box").slideToggle(400);
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $("#empty-box").slideUp(); 
    }, 5000);
    return false;
});
$("#empty-box").on("click", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).on("click", function () {
    $("#empty-box").slideUp(400);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign your call to `setTimeout` to a variable declared in the outer scope and clear it with `clearTimeout` in every subsequent event:

```
var timeout;
$('#box-link').click(function(event){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    event.stopPropagation();
    $("#empty-box").slideToggle(400);
    timeout = setTimeout(function() { 
        $("#empty-box").slideUp(); 
    }, 5000);
    return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

The `setTimeout` function returns a value that you can cancel using `clearTimeout`.

So in your code, store the return value, and each time it is clicked, cancel the previous timeout and restart a new one.

```
var timeout = null;
function test()
{
    if( timeout !== null )
          clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(..., 10000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple, really. The key is placing your setTimeout in a `variable` and calling `clearTimeout(variable)`.

Example:

```js
let someVar = false,
    someTime = 5000,
    msgTimer = document.getElementById('timer'),
    timer, 
    current,
    displayTimer = false;

$('.yourButton').on('click', someFunc)

function someFunc() {
  if (someVar) {
    clearTimeout(someVar)               // <<< juice is here
    console.log('cleared timeout!')
  }
  timer = performance.now()
  someVar = setTimeout(function () {
    clearInterval(displayTimer)
    console.log(someTime / 1000 + 
    ' seconds passed since last click...')
    someVar = false
    displayTimer = false
    msgTimer.innerHTML = ''    
  }, someTime)

  /**
   * ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
   * ignore past this point, rest is timer
   *
   * ˙ʇᴉ pǝǝu ʇ,uop no⅄ ˙ʎllɐǝɹ
   **/

  if (displayTimer) { 
    clearInterval(displayTimer)
    displayTimer = false
  }
  displayTimer = setInterval(function () {
    current = performance.now()
    msgTimer.innerHTML = Math.max(timer + 5000 - current,0)
    .toFixed(2) + 'ms'
  }, 15)
}
```

```css
#timer {
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align:right;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="yourButton">Don't click. Think.</button>
<span id="timer"></span>
```

Reduced interval to 5 seconds for faster testing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to show a `div` for a maximum of 10 seconds...

And hide it if user clicks anywhere before this delay.
There is no problem with the delay if user clicks often or repeately...
Because I took care of resets.

I created a [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/jmQEMy?editors=1010), with a timer displayed aside the cart link, to show the time passing.
And here is a [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/ZKmYXv) with the exact same code as in the below snippet, if your want to play with it.

```js
var emptyCart = $("#emptyCart");
var cartTimer;
var carMaxTime = 10000;

// Function to hide the cart
var hideCart = function(){
  emptyCart.dequeue().slideUp("slow");
}

// Function to show the cart
var showCart = function(){
  emptyCart.dequeue().slideDown("slow");
  clearTimeout(cartTimer);            // Just to be sure We have only one timer running
  cartTimer = setTimeout(function(){
    hideCart();
  },carMaxTime);
}

// Function to handle click on the cart link
$("#clickCart").click(function(){
  $(document).off("click",hideCart());  // Just to prevent a slideUp which would counter-act a slideUp

  if(emptyCart.is(":hidden")){
    showCart();
  }
  setTimeout(function(){                // 1ms delay to use this event handler on next click.
    $(document).on("click",function(){
      hideCart();
      $(document).off("click",hideCart());  // Unbind this handler once used.
    });
  },1);
});
```

```css
#emptyCart{
  display:none;
  width:100px;
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
  height:30px;
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="clickCart">
  <a href="#">Cart</a>
</div>
<div id="emptyCart">
  No items
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses everyone! I ended up going with Mikael's solution since I only had to modify 3 lines of code. Appreciate the help!